Why can't the mutual attraction between two parallel AC currents (in the same phase) be used to define an ampere for AC currents?
I encountered this text while reading about AC currents:

Both alternating current and direct current are measured in amperes.
But how is the ampere defined for an alternating current? It cannot be
derived from the mutual attraction of two parallel wires carrying ac
currents, as the dc ampere is derived. An ac current changes direction with the source frequency and the attractive force would average to
zero.

But if the ac currents in the two wires are always in phase, then they should always attract, since parallel currents attract each other; and the net force should not be 0. So why don't we use this to define an ampere for ac current?

They do not always attract, the sign of the force alternates with the separation distance (roughly periodic with the wavelength). See a previous answer of mine for quantitative details: "Average force between two parallel finite wires with AC"

@LPZ I don't know enough physics to understand the quantitative explanation you sent, but thank you nonetheless. Am I to understand that the "parallel currents attract and anti-parallel currents repel"  rule only applies for steady dc currents?

In short yes, a better rule of thumb for AC currents is that even integer wavelengths it is attractive like in DC but at odd integer wavelengths it is repulsive (applies at large distance)

@LPZ the average force will be 0 regardless of the phase difference of the 2 circuits.

@RootGroves I'm not sure I follow. Even in the low frequency limit, you should recover Ampère's force law, so the force does not average to zero.

@LPZ I agree. In the magneto quasi static approximation the force is always attractive. The magnitude oscillates between 0 and the maximum, but the direction is always attractive.

@Dale Glad we agree in the quasi static limit :). However in the radiative zone, since the magnetic field alternates in sign, the force should too
